# How to create a cell for phone number and callback number

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cell, calculation

I have a callback number that looks like ex *123445660 to call out to a country. The star needs to be included to for the callback to work.
So for example I copy a number in our software and then I get the string " 1 mobile +4570541198"
I would like to do a cell that just pass the nine last numbers and then add the callback number too it, so it would look like *1234566070541198.
I know you can write =right,9 to fetch the last 9, but how do I do next to get the callback number added?

Tried to create a single cell that will add the callback number to the =right function. To see if it is possible to do it in one cell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for array you will need:

```
=INDEX("*1234566"&RIGHT(A1:A; 9))
```

Comment: This works good if you have a lot of numbers. I only need to add one number temerparly each time.

Comment: @Linkinpark for one number is: `="*1234566"&RIGHT(A1; 9)`

Answer (score 1):

use the following syntax:

```
=(CONCAT(A1,RIGHT(B1,8)))
```

[image: it would look like this]

Comment: This is good if you have stored numbers in the sheet. For this I do only do not store any numbers and only need a forumla that adds the last 9 of a number plus the dial back number.

Comment: @Linkinpark This formula does what you are asking for. Except it adds the last 8 characters not 9.

Comment: Yes I know, but would it not be possible to narrow it down to just two cells? On containing the pasted number, the other one generating the output ex "string,right..." done. Then I woul just need two cells and could copy the formula output as finished callback number?

Comment: @Linkinpark : you could replace **Cell Name** with any string you would like.. replace cell name **A1** by text **"*123445660"**

Comment: This worked great, thanks. One more question if it is okay. Is it possible to make a cell that does not display anything until the "input number" cell is field? Just thinking that I could just put the callback number on a nother spreadsheet page and then link it back to the main sheet. Like it is now the callback number is shown all the time even without input data from the input number. This is ofcourse not a problem, more esthetic and more clean to only show thr output cell with a value when all is field in.